# ASIHTTPRequest: Encoding in post data

Tags: iphone, encoding, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to send a form this way:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:foo forKey:@"post_var"];
```

How can I set the encoding of the nsstring foo??

The web receiving the form data expects the value in ISOLatin1

Answer (score 3):

ASIFormDataRequests allow to you set the encoding of content sent to the server like this:

```
[request setStringEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding].
```

The default is NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *_cFoo = "bar";
NSString *_foo = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:_cFoo encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:_foo forKey:@"post_var"];
// ...
[request trigger];
[_foo release];
```

**EDIT**: I'm not sure why the above wouldn't work. I guess I should try it out. But looking at the source for ASIHTTPRequest, the `-setPostValue:forKey:` method looks like it takes any `NSObject` subclass for a POST value:

```
- (void)setPostValue:(id <NSObject>)value forKey:(NSString *)key
{
   if (![self postData]) {
       [self setPostData:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
   }
   [[self postData] setValue:[value description] forKey:key];
   [self setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
}
```

Perhaps convert an `NSString` to a C string and use its `NSData` representation as the POST variable value:

```
NSString *_foo = @"bar";
const char *_cFoo = [_foo cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSData *_cFooData = [NSData dataWithBytes:_cFoo length:strlen(_cFoo)];
[request setPostValue:_cFooData forKey:@"post_var"];
```

Comment: The point is I already have an UTF8 encoded NSString. Following your example:

c_Foo = [foo UTF8String];
......

It's not working. I dont get ISOLatin1 encoded strings :-(

Comment: Doing that, I get values like this: <6275656e f3212121 2121> in the form receiver.